# Embedded sensor module design - external functions

Tags: c, module, embedded

I have one small question about proper module design for embedded device (different manufacturer, cortex M0 - M7).

Lets say we have c sensor module for reading accelerometer data from I2C device *acc.c* and corresponding headerfile *acc.h*.
Module needs external functions for I2C communication. And I am thinking about correct implementation of module.
Until now I have in my mind these 3 versions:

1. *Include I2C.h* driver (This option is last option, because it will fix module usage to one platform)
2. *Weak definition* of externaly provided functions (But again weak definition of function is pretty fixed on platform - NXP has different implementation than STM etc)
3. *Function pointers* in process structure, so every device would have assigned external function for I2C communication (It seems to be little bit overkill for this kind of device and debugging of such implementation can be little bit tricky, but overall implementation seems to be clean).

Do you have any ideas for better solution which would be more readable/debuggable than function pointers and still portable?

Comment: `i2c.h` is  only the header file not the driver.

Comment: Simple abstract  the communication functions. Your i2c.c should define functions like i2cread and i2cwrite. Then you will nonly have to change this file to port it to another platform. Nothing else needed.

Comment: But it comes to problem, when there will be more than one I2c peripheral used or am I wrong?

Comment: i2cwrite(int i2c, void *data, size_t len)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the whole sensor module will be delivered as: acc.c acc.h and i2c.c. In i2c.c will be included module for specific platform i2c and then implemented functions i2cwrite and i2cread. The i2c.c will be somethink like interface for module (which has to be implemented before using the module). Did I get it right?